# Community Promotion Ads - 4Q 2011

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/857/community-promotion-ads-2013)

### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site

The goal is for future visitors to find out about the *stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

### How does it work?

All answers should be in the exact form of:

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: http://image-url
   [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Please do not add anything else to the body of the post. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.

### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

### Score Threshold

There is a minimum score threshold an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Join CUBRID Q&A Event now!]

Comment: Out of curiousity, why does cubrid feel the need to run an OSQA instance on it's own? There's already ask.sqlservercentral etc

Comment: CUBRID Q&A site isn't powered by OSQA but by open source CMS [XE](http://www.xpressengine.org). We've developed the Kin (Q&A) module for XE which we contributed to XE community. This is one reason. But the main reason is that new users search for CUBRID answers not on sqlservercentral.com, which is for SQL Server anyway, but on the project community site.

Comment: It just seems to me, as a human with misunderstanding at every turn, that you're asking us to help sponsor a new database Q&A site (which in the spirit of community I can back). But do we really want to send DB users to another Q&A site, or do we just want product recognition and name-sharing for CUBRID?

Comment: @jcolebrand - We should instead be attracting the users of this product here if it's Q&A they want, no? That's what we exist for.

Comment: Exactly. Having questions asked on SO is also really good option which we have also considered. In fact, there are some already asked here. In any case, for CUBRID community our final goal is to provide answers doesn't matter on SO or cubrid.org. Of course, preferable on the project site, but definitely not on other DB vendor site (doesn't make sense). All we want is good questions about CUBRID to answer to. You all at SO know why. Our goal is a subset of SO goal. If there is a chance to encourage SO users to ask questions related to CUBRID, we would be very glad. Also suggestions are welcomed

Comment: @Eye I wonder if you can give us final feedback on where you ended up on this?

Comment: Well, I ended up seeing 4 down votes. That's all. Anyway, we've gone forward and established the Q&A site at http://www.cubrid.org/questions for the community. In addition, we're subscribed to "cubrid" tag on SO so that we get notified of new related question as soon as they're asked. Other than that, I don't know how to "promote" this idea to SO community, if that was the question. Anyway, thank you for showing your interest.